# Asymptotic density of an infinite union of subgroups

Tags: probability, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Let $1 < a_1 < a_2 < a_3 <{} ...$ be a sequence of integers. For a subset $A \subset \Bbb Z$, denote by $d(A)$ its natural density (if it exists).

> Is it true that $$ 
> \lim_{N \to +\infty} 
> d\Big( \bigcup_{i \leq N} a_i \Bbb Z \Big) 
> = 
> d\Big( \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_i \Bbb Z \Big)$$?

The density of the finite union $\bigcup_{i \leq N} a_i \Bbb Z$ can be computed via the inclusion-exclusion principle, but it is not clear how it would relate to the infinite union.

Comment: Great question!

Comment: If we define $U_N := \bigcup_{i=1}^N  a_i \Bbb Z$ the the above equality is equivalent to interchanging two limits $$ \lim_{X \to + \infty} \lim_{N \to + \infty}    \frac{ |U_N \cap [1, X]| }{ X } = \lim_{N \to + \infty} \lim_{X \to + \infty}    \frac{ |U_N \cap [1, X]| }{ X }.$$

Comment: Note: it does not work if we replace $a_i \Bbb Z$ by $\{ i \}$.

Comment: This does not work for sets of positive density: take $A_i = 2 \Bbb Z \cup \{ i \}$.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447362/asymptotic-density-of-an-infinite-union-of-subgroups